# Store data retrieved as result of find_by_sql method in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, find-by-sql

I am new to ruby on rails. I am trying to retrieve data from my database and make operation in my rails application. I am stuck while trying to use find_by_sql in my class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

I have a rates table with structure as

```
id | Instrument Name | Category | Time_of_usage | Rates
1  | Instrument1     | Internal | Regular       | 25
2  | Instrument2     | Internal | Weekends      | 15
```

Here is my sample code of what I am trying to achieve

```
sql2='SELECT Rates FROM New_billcodes_mock WHERE Category_name=?, Instrument_name=? and Time_zone_name=?'
result2=  find_by_sql[sql2,'Internal','Instrument1',time_zone_name]
database_billrate_value_normal=result2['Rates']
```

and use the database_billrate_value_normal variable to make my operations.

Please guide me in the correct path if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear if the model with the rate table is Activity or NewBillcodeMock or Rate.

If it is Rate, you should be able to do something like this:

```
database_billrate_value_normal = 
    Rate.where("category_name=? AND 
                instrument_name=? AND 
                time_zone_name=?",
                params[:category_name],
                params[:instrument_name],
                params[:time_zone_name]).pluck[:rates]
```

... assuming you have a hash `params` with the required attribute values those are the actual attribute names.

This will return an array of rates which you can then manipulate directly in Ruby as needed.

Comment: The name of the table is New_billcodes_mock, the attribute values that I want to retrieve are Rates. If I were to use 'where' method what would be the class of the variable database_billrate_value_normal?

Comment: Ruby utilizes [duck typing](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/duck_typing.html), so there is no need to type variables.  You should also look into Rails naming conventions like [this one](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions) for Active Record and [this one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#controller-naming-convention) for controllers.  There are a number of other very good sources.  Starting off with a fundamental knowledge of Rails conventions can save a lot of grief down the road.

Comment: I have a table name 'Times' in my database, when I try to run query on it as result1=Times.where("id=?","1") I am getting an error message "NameError (uninitialized constant Activity::Times):"

Comment: Is there a Times instance with `id` of 1? If so, you can use `Times.find(1)`.